# docker image cp-kafka and schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

i have the docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - kafka
  schemaregistry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
    container_name: schemaregistry
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schemaregistry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schemaregistry:8085
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    networks:
      - kafka
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schemaregistry:8085
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: false
    networks:
      - kafka
      
      
networks:
  kafka:
```

When i'm trying to create topic i recieve the error.

```
docker exec broker kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server broker:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic my-new-topic --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true
Error while executing topic command : Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.schema.validation
[2022-12-02 14:05:53,318] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.schema.validation
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

i've looked in https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/LogConfig.scala and there is no schema config.
Is it ok? Is schema registry feature supporting by cp-kafka? maybe cp-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, that config option only is applicable for topics managed by `cp-server` image (which does not have available open-source code).